# Zombie's Detection Of Prey

Tags: science-based, zombies

A while ago I was watching The Walking Dead (Season 1) with my sister, and we came across that one scene where Rick and his group theorize that zombies detect humans via smell, but here's the problem: ZOMBIES ARE DEAD (mostly) AND CANNOT BREATHE!! DUN DUN DUN!!!

Alternative Ways Zed detect prey:

Hearing: It's necessary but not enough, as the zombie cannot tell if it's coming from another zombie, a human, an explosion or whatever.

Touch/taste: No. Just No.

Sight: Maybe but I doubt dried up eyeballs are of any good or if the zombies are smart enough to tell if it's a human

So the question is to find a way zombies could accurately detect the presense of humans nearby so they could walk over and eat them, without relying on the senses above (Unless you could prove them reliable for zombies to use)

EDIT: **THIS QUESTION IS NOT ABOUT MAGIC ZOMBIES! AS THE TAGS STATE THIS IS  SCIENCE-BASED!** I know how ridiculous actual undead zombies might sound like but we are getting closer!

EDIT NO.2: The zombies are partially alive, as their nervous system still exists. I still consider them undead because most of their bodily functions are down and they are recently dead people revived by the zombie pathogen. People have been reported to be saved 3 hours after they are supposed to die so I think it's possible.

Comment: I am not sure the 'zombies do not breathe' part is accurate, although I have never met a zombie to know for sure. Somehow, however, they need to metabolize something for energy in the muscles, don't they?

Comment: Zombies are anaerobic, we've established that in the last question when we were talking about how to release the lactic acid which is a byproduct of anaerobic respiration

Comment: That just means zombies don't *have* to breathe to supply oxygen, it doesn't mean they *can't* breathe for other reasons... like smelling things, or moaning "braaaaains".

Comment: Huh... maybe I'll consider that but humans have a bad sense of smell compared to other animals, and also if the zombies don't breathe they consume less energy daily allowing them to survive longer.

Comment: Actually, I believe the OP may be right. In damaged brains, smell is one of the first senses to go. Take a look at [this post](https://zombieresearchsociety.com/archives/36221) for some interesting food for thought.

Comment: Zombies are necessarily magic... in the absense of magic, they just don't work. Therefore, the way they sense humans is magic.

Comment: We are discussing a way to make actual scientific zombies as the tags state. Please don't talk about magic here. Please. We are doing okay so far, we just need a little push

Comment: @Hi0401 nah, there's always magic, or pseudoscientific handwaving (which may as well be magic) or "sufficiently advanced technology" and we all know what Clarke said about that. Even in your previous answers you've ended up with "nanotechnology" which is just three different kinds of magic in a trenchcoat. Don't sweat it, that's just the nature of zombies. If you want zombies, you gotta put up with the magic, too.

Comment: Not this time! Im striving to write the first zombie story that is actually scientific! :) I ended up abandoning the nanobot part, because even though it was cool it didn't give me the effects I wanted and would probably make the story take place in the far future.

Comment: What about being dead makes one unable to breathe? The zombies exhibit other muscle control otherwise they won't be able to move or open or even move their eyes. If they have muscle control, then what stops them from voluntarily inhaling air? They don't have to breathe, the same way you don't have to open or close your mouth. You can still choose to do it, though.

Comment: Something about the brain stem I suppose.

Answer (score 4):

## Auditory Hyperesthesia

Induced by the unbearable Neuropathic pain associated with zombie physiology, zombies become hypersensitive to sound. They are now especially good at hearing and processing different sounds. Especially sounds that they are very familiar with, specifically the sound of **a human heart beating**.

In the question it says that hearing isn't enough, well it is now that it has been heightened and inadvertently trained (by the zombie's previous human life, hearing their own heartbeat). They can not only tell the difference between explosions, humans, and other zombies, but also the difference between a dog's heartbeat and a human's heartbeat. They can also determine the direction and approximate distance to the heartbeats that they hear, as well as any other sounds that the unfortunate humans make in addition to their beating hearts.

Comment: Interesting. Sounds like something from ROTLD. I'll keep this in mind, may use it later

Answer (score 3):

**Zombies smell using their skin**.

[Association between Olfactory Receptors and Skin Physiology](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8989906/)

> Olfactory receptors are chemosensory receptors that detect odorants
> and function in the initial perception of a smell. Intriguingly,
> olfactory receptors are also expressed in cells other than olfaction
> sensory cells, an expression pattern termed ectopic expression...
> This review introduces current research on the ectopic expression and
> function of olfactory receptors in skin and provides insight into
> directions for future research.

Humans have smell receptors in our skin.  Sandalwood olfactory receptor is one the linked article discusses.  The zombification process augments this.  Olfactory receptors sprout up all over the zombie body.  Exposure to air stimulates expression of these receptors.  The zombie thus can smell just by air blowing across the body.  As clothes fall off and wounds open up the surface area available for ectopic olfactory receptors increases.  The sense of smell improves.

Zombies are attracted to human exhalations and other live human specific smells.  Possibly they are attracted to zombie smells too but not as prey - Z likes to cluster because there is strength in numbers.   This effect offers the possibility of smell bombs to attract away zombies.  Also the possibility of treating zombies with attractive smells such that they will be attacked by other zombies and maybe attack themselves.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just not sure if this will work if zombies had clothing on, or what they will resort to when their skin gets eaten by the zombification bacteria for nutrients.

Comment: I'm also not sure if this is enough to detect human activity as stated up there in the question, but maybe that's just because I am dumb :(

Answer (score 2):

**They can't because, under the [science-based](/questions/tagged/science-based) tag, they can't exist**

I suspect you didn't read that tag's wiki before using it. It requires all answers to be entirely science-based. Zombies are dead. Olefactory doesn't work. Auditory doesn't work. Visual doesn't work. The Brain isn't working. The idea of a magic virus that can keep the brain alive without oxygen and can allow it to process complex signals simply doesn't meet the restrictions of the tag.

So, let's shift to the [science-fiction](/questions/tagged/science-fiction) tag.<sup>1</sup>

Now, the problem with this is that as soon as you suggest that the zombie's ears and eyes are working, what's to say the nose isn't either? Muscles decay without oxygen so the lungs are still needed. Even if you suggest that whatever is sustaining the zombie is taking care of that, the reflex of breathing would still be built into the brain. (you have some control over your breathing, but for the most part, you don't breathe by choice.) So the sense of smell works just fine.

*But, we want a solution that doesn't involve smell, well... because.*

- The process of zombification shifts the visual spectrum of the eye toward the infra-red. They can see heat signatures.
- Zombification results in a form of autism, causing frighteningly high sensitivity to both sound and light.
- The skin nerves are seriously heightened, causing pain even in a light breeze, but as a result, they can feel the motions of things around them. But it also means they can feel "dirty" in the presence of living humans in the same way that we often feel "dirty" in the presence of dead things.<sup>1</sup>
- The virus (since we're reflecting science to some degree here) that causes zombification crates a nodule in the brain that acts in a way similar to the sensory navigation in birds: it detects the minute magnetic field caused by a large, living brain.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> *I'm going to post a Meta question about modifying the three science tags to include the requirement that the tag can't be used unless the question also meets the conditions of the tag. It's not reasonable that a [science-fiction](/questions/tagged/science-fiction) question should be allowed to use the [science-based](/questions/tagged/science-based) or [hard-science](/questions/tagged/hard-science) tags just because the OP think's it's fun to try and get a "better answer."*</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> *Note that the human "feeling" or intuition I'm talking about is actually a complex reaction to a combination of sight, smell, taste, and touch. It's similar to the [feeling of being watched](https://www.bbc.com/future/article/20170512-what-causes-that-feeling-of-being-watched). But we'll ignore all that for the purpose of this answer.*</sub>

Comment: The brain is alive. (But is mutated) and maybe the neurons throughout the body are too. But that's it. I haven't specified that yet, will edit

Comment: @Hi0401
 I am sorry, but dead is dead. You can not posit  a live brain in a body that can not support it. It needs a circulatory system to constantly replace the millions of cells that are dying hourly. Even if all that is functioning is the lower brainstem. Without some circulatory mechanism to continually replace these cells, your science based premise is as dead as the brain.

Comment: Brain cells can't be replaced I think and I will address these problems in another question. I remember how cockroaches can live after being dismembered because of how blood is distributed around it's body, so yeah.

Comment: I don't really understand why everyone is talking about how a zombie won't be able to move with dead muscles. People walk when the brain fires signals to the muscles that result in the muscles contracting or something. This can be done to dead frogs so they could move after death. I've seen news/video clips about SKINNED dead toads jumping around because they are still being stimulated by the environment, why can't dead humans move in the same fashion? As for the muscle healing part I believe that muscles won't be damaged unless you use a certain amount of force... right?

Comment: @Hi0401 My primary point is that it's a bit unreasonable to ask for a science-based answer when you don't have a science-based question. Picking and choosing what science to use and what to ignore is what science-fiction is all about. Also, please note that there's a difference between a recently brain dead creature (chicken running around with its head cut off) and a dead creature (dead muscles). Once a cell dies, that cell can no longer contribute to contraction. Once enough cells are dead, the muscle can't contract even if a taser is applied.

Comment: @JBH Okay... anything else? I can't tell if it's really scientific but I am trying, so if it appears as sci-fi it's because I don't know. Now that you've said that I'm willing to stretch the boundaries a little, considering how some zombie fiction depict only recently dead people reanimating

Comment: @JBH But why can't dead muscle move anyways? Is it because of decomposition? Or something to do with the nerve cells? I mean in the toad example up there that thing has obviously been dead for a while, also its skinned and everything

Comment: @JBH Now that I think about it I want to accept your answer, but please answer these two questions for me to be extra sure: (Let's throw away the undead part for now) Is it possible for a nodule to form due to a bacterial infection that detects human brains that are not yet also infected&mutated (They will still go after someone who is infected but not zombified) within... a radius of 10 meters, let's say, and cause the zombie to head towards said human and try to chomp on them? When the victim is being zombified and the nodule is starting to form, can it do so completely within an hour?

Comment: @Hi0401 (a) It's uncommon for any biological thing to form in just an hour. The more complex the behavior of the thing, the longer it takes to form. The nodule you're talking about is much more complex than it seems. (b) I know of nothing that will not infect a creature because it's already infected. The reality is that no one can tell that such an event has occurred. It's like trying to detect that a glass of salt water had been poured into the ocean. (c) We've been very unspecific about the discussion of "move." If I apply enough electricity to a chicken thigh I buy from the (\*continued\*)

Comment: ... butcher, no matter how long it's been there, it will contract. But I can say the same for a block of plastic. If I apply enough electricity, I can make it move, too (although it'll be through explosive force rather than contractive force). But the longer you wait, *the less it's capable of doing so under the much weaker conditions of nerve control.* Eventually, the chicken with its head cut off falls over, and with each passing second, the degradation of nerves, nerve endings, and muscles, weakens the flesh's ability to operate under the brain's (or similar) control. (\*Continued\*)

Comment: ... Perhaps you should stop reading about the frog and read about people who suffer from muscle necrosis. It's very hard if not often impossible for a living person to move muscles that have, basically, died. (d) Finally, I think part of the problem we're having is that you're insisting on finding a science-provable way for something that isn't science-based to exist. It isn't going to happen. Authors have come up with ingenious ways to *rationalize* zombies such that they have a wonderfully believable flavor. But if you look at those rationalizations, (\*Continued\*)

Comment: ... you'll discover that absolutely none of them hold up to science. Forcing a muscle to move for long periods of time through means that have nothing to do with bodily functions is obviously possible. Animating the dead isn't. We're here to help you build an imaginary world. We're not here to help you prove something scientifically impossible is possible.

Comment: I think you are talking about how dead tissue won't function because the neurons in the muscles are dead too, I can work with that. I think they are considered to be part of the nervous system so I can leave them there. As I said I am willing to twist the boundaries.

Comment: "We're here to help you build an imaginary world. We're not here to help you prove something scientifically impossible is possible." "It's not reasonable that a science-fiction question should be allowed to use the science-based or hard-science tags just because the OP think's it's fun to try and get a "better answer."" No, that's not true. You're acting like I am trying to pose an impossible question on purpose, but if I was supposed to know how everything is supposed to work why would I be here on worldbuilding?

Comment: As far as I know you tag something science based when you want to be scientific but you are doubt if your assumptions are correct and want to make sure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141822/discussion-between-hi0401-and-jbh).

Comment: @Hi0401 Please take the time to read the [tag:scieince-based] wiki.

Comment: Can you give me the link please?

Comment: @Hi0401 It would help if I could spell, but you could have used the link in my answer. Or the link in your own question. But, for convenience, click the [tag:science-based] link, then click the "Learn More..." link. Or you can click "tags" in the left column, search for "science-based" (although it usually lists first), then click the "Learn More..." link. Becoming familiar with tags is a good thing.

Comment: Think I finished reading, I don't see a problem

Comment: The deal killer here is the statement, "Questions with this tag should be answered, as far as possible, using known scientific facts or reasonable extrapolations from known scientific facts. The answers are not required to provide scientific citations or be held strictly to rigid scientific interpretation." Your zombies are dead. They can't walk, much less detect anything. No known virus (or anything else) can manifest a zombie. You're asking for a science-based answer to a non-science-based question. There is no extrapolation to be made from Real World science.

Answer (score 1):

**Motion and heat detection**
If we are talking about a zombie that is created via infection the only reason why they would "decay" like magic zombies is that whatever is infecting them is also consuming their bodies. With that in mind the sickness can pick and choose organs that gets consumed, so you could have a zombie who's brain has been partially consumed but still have advanced hearing or even sight. However the zombie would not have the cognitive ability to make sense of its enviorment again, due to its damaged brain so he would really on special triggers- if it moves like a human it can enter a state of hysteria- that would also trigger hysterical strenght. On top of that zombies having colder bodies is possible that they can feel heat from the distance- maybe even develop thermovision depending on the virus, so this way they can locate prey.

Answer (score 0):

OK! If you are looking for something with at least a pseudo-scientific explanation and level of believability, (pseudo, because... Zombies), then the Z's are most likely 'Infected' rather than 'Undead'.
Infected could use any of the normal human senses, potentially further modified by the pathogen which caused zombification.
If you really want to go with Undead/Reanimated, and insist that the eyes and nose dry up and that oxygen is not required for sense and mobility, then you can still potentially use Auditory cues - the ears will be less affected by dried up mucous membranes (since unlike eyes, mouth and nose they don't have any), and the sensory parts of the brain could conceivably continue to function minimally on stored fats, as in ketosis, rather than glucose and glycolysis.
This would give the 'Undead/Reanimated' Z's a rather limited (un)lifespan of course, since they will run out of sensory neuron nourishment rather quickly. Maybe that's why they crave brains?
If you want to go full-on Peter Hamilton/Charles Stross SciFi, then the neural systems of the Reanimated could be made functional by an extradimensional force, but then you aren't really dealing with Zombies, rather they become the Possessed.